# storing parameters and standardized coefficients from stepwise regression as vectors

Tags: r

I am using this code to extract standardized parameter coefficients (`lm.beta` from QuantPsyc package) for a set of linear models generated with stepwise linear regression (`stepAIC` from MASS package) in a for loop.

```
fit <- lm(mymodel)
step <- stepAIC(fit, direction="both")
stdcoefs <- lm.beta(step)
```

`lm.beta` returns the coefficients in separate columns for each parameter. How can I write these to a data frame and store the parameters and coefficients as two vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

For your question we don't really need the stepAIC function. I just use the lm.beta function because this is what you ask. Take a look at the following example:

```
library(MASS)
library(QuantPsyc)

Y  <- runif(100)
X1 <- runif(100)
X2 <- runif(100)
X3 <- runif(100)
X4 <- runif(100)
df <- data.frame(Y,X1,X2,X3,X4)

fit <- lm(df)
step <- stepAIC(fit, direction="both")
stdcoefs <- lm.beta(step)
a <- unname(stdcoefs)  #stores coefficients in vector a
b <- names(stdcoefs)   #stores parameters in vector b

> a
[1] 0.1486643
> b
[1] "X3"
```

Comment: This will store coefficients and parameters from the full model. However, I only need them from the final model chosen by `stepAIC`. Using `lm.beta` to get the standardized coefficients may not be the correct way to do this. Other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: And use exactly the same code. it will save it. I ll show a new example

Comment: check this new example. Works exactly the same. lm.beta is fine.

Comment: In the case you may have additional insight, I posted a follow-up question here: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27114389/write-results-from-stepaic-to-a-table