# Write results from stepAIC to a table

Tags: r

I am trying to write r2, rmse, coefficients, and standardized coefficients from `stepAIC` to a .CSV file:

```
NO3_lmres_ClimateOnly <- data.frame()
for (i in unique(Data$SeasAlltxt)){
  print (i)
  subdata1 <- subset(Data, SeasAlltxt == i)
  for (j in unique(Data$ALSCIDtxtall)){
    subdata2 <- subset(subdata1, ALSCIDtxtall == j)
    fit <- lm(NO3resid~Avg94NO3+MaxDepth_m+MaxDepthDOY+FirstZeroDOY+PeakToGone+PRISMppt+PRISMtmax, data = subdata2, na.action = na.omit)
    step <- stepAIC(fit, direction="both")

    rmse <- round(sqrt(mean(resid(step)^2)), 3)
    r2 <- round(summary(step)$r.squared, 3)
    coefs <- summary(step)$coefficients
    stdcoefs <- lm.beta(step)
    stdcoefs <- unname(stdcoefs)
    params <- names(stdcoefs)

    tempvalues <- data.frame(i,j,rmse,r2,coefs,stdcoefs,params)
    colnames(tempvalues) <- c('SeasAlltxt', 'ALSCIDtxtall', 'rmse', 'r2', 'coef', 'stdcoef','param')
    NO3_lmres_ClimateOnly <- rbind(NO3_lmres_ClimateOnly,tempvalues)
  }
}

write.csv(NO3_lmres_ClimateOnly, file = "NO3_ClimateOnly_stats.csv")
```

However, the above code produces this error:

```
Error in data.frame(i, j, rmse, r2, coefs, stdcoefs, params) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 3, 2, 0
```

I would also like to write the p-value associated with each parameter to the output table.

Any suggestions for how to accomplish this?

Comment: In a dataframe all columns need to have exactly the same number of rows. In your case i,j are just single numbers whereas coefs are probably a vector of numbers, thus the error.

Comment: I had a feeling that is what was causing the error. Is there a work around for this? Possibly to repeat i,j,rmse and r2 for each coefficient?

Comment: use a list() if you want to keep the same format. otherwise save the coefficients separately in a different list.

Comment: I just tested writing only the coefficients to the data frame (i.e. removed i,j,rmse, and r2) and still get a similar error. Only difference is that there is no value of "1" in the list of numbers shown in the error.

Comment: How would I go about using list()?

Comment: you will get the same error with the coefficients if the number of coeficients changes every turn. instead of data.frame() use list()

Comment: I tried list() and this gave me an error with the colnames line: attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions. ...without using list(), I am able to write out everything I need if I REMOVE stdcoefs from the specified output. I may just proceed without these. `lm.beta` also seems to be disrupting the for loop for some reason. (I think it this is caused by `lm.beta` attempting to do standardized coefficients on a model without any parameters (intercept-only). If I comment that line out, everything runs fine. it seems that `lm.beta` is what is causing the troubles.

Comment: "I think it this is caused by lm.beta attempting to do standardized coefficients on a model without any parameters (intercept-only)". You are right about this. Try and save stdcoefs separately if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to change your code:

```
for (j in unique(subdata1$ALSCIDtxtall))
```

...

```
 coefs <- summary(step)$coefficients[,1]
```

...

```
tempvalues  <- data.frame(t(c(i,j,rmse,r2,coefs,stdcoefs,params)),stringsAsFactors=F)
colnames(tempvalues ) <- c('SeasAlltxt', 'ALSCIDtxtall', 'rmse', 'r2', names(coefs), paste('stdcoef:',params),params)
```

Bud the final rbind will give you an error when *stepAIC* select different number of coefficients.

Think of using a list instead:

Define `cont=1` outside the *for*
then, change the following lines:

```
tempvalues  <- data.frame(t(c(i,j,rmse,r2,coefs,stdcoefs,params)),stringsAsFactors=F)
    colnames(tempvalues ) <- c('SeasAlltxt', 'ALSCIDtxtall', 'rmse', 'r2', names(coefs), paste('stdcoef:',params),params)
    NO3_lmres_ClimateOnly[[cont]] <- tempvalues
    cont=cont+1
```

Good luck!!

Comment: Also for using lists, define 'NO3_lmres_ClimateOnly <- list()'